# Help with Modeling Shotgun Handle

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode

I've been trying to model a sawed-off shotgun and have run into a wall on how to model the handle. The general shape isn't too much of an issue as I just extruded a plane based off of a reference image (the second image), but there are sections that I don't know how to model.

For instance, the handle transitions from a circular base to a more squared-off shape. Also, on the sides there is a raised, triangular portion that I've found is tricky to model.

Any advice on how to go about modeling this would be greatly appreciated.

Reference Images:
[image: The circled portion is an issue area, especially the transition from triangular point to the handle.]

[image: The base of the handle starts circular, but when it attaches to the barrel portion it is square.]

What I've tried so far:
[image: I feel I have the general shape, just missing the difficult to model portions.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm lazy, so I'd let Blender do most of the job.
Make the rectangular part and the round part, and let Blender make the transition for you.

*A nice final render (to boost my ego)*
[image]

**Project blend file for your inspiration:**
[image]

**01) Square part**
- Start with a basic cube, add loopcuts, extrude it and stuff...
- Use proportional editing (I used *Sharp* profile)
- Use subsurf modifier

*Use proportional editing for those tapered edges*
[image]

**02) Round part**
- I used a basic cylinder and extruded it.
- Just make sure the number of vertices (and edges) is the same as in the open loop of the square part.
It's 24 vertices (and edges) in this case.

**03) Bridge Edge loops**
- Select and bridge the two edge loops (*Edge > Bridge Edge Loops*)
- Both loops need to have the same number of vertices
- Both meshes need to be in one object (you can join them into one with <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd>)

[image]

[image]

Comment: What would be optimal to use for the smoothing? As sub-surface distorts my model.

Comment: Hello :). There could be some problem with topology, hard to say. Ask this as a new question, and I'll be sure to look into that.